# Django Many to Many circular reference?

Tags: python, django

conceptually what I want is this:

```
class Child:
    guardians = models.ManyToManyField(Guardian)

class Guardian:
    children = models.ManyToManyField(Child)
```

The application is for a school. Any one parent(guardian) can have multiple children and any child can have multiple guardians. Now, I can't forward declare in python as I would in C++.

What is the cleanest and best way to do this? Do I need a third 'Relationship' class to represent these connections (this is what I'm tending towards)? But before I reinvent the wheel I wanted to ask. It seems like this should be easy...

Comment: You absolutely don't need to declare the relationship on both sides. Pick one only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the problem.

By doing this:

```
class Child:
    guardians = models.ManyToManyField('Guardian', related_name='children')

class Guardian:
    .... some other fields
    # children = models.ManyToManyField(Child)  <--- not needed
```

Is like saying "a child can have many guardians and a guardian can have many children". You
don't have to declare it in both models.

Also a third(intermediate) table is created anyway by django, behind the scenes. Because
this is how you model ManyToMany relationships in an RDBMS.

The only reason you'd want to **explicitly** create an intermediate model, is when you
have to put extra information that describes the specific many2many relationship.
i.e.

```
class Child:
    guardians = models.ManyToManyField('Guardian', 
        through='ChildGuardianMembership', related_name='children')

class Guardian:
    .... some other fields

class ChildGuardianMembership:
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child)
    guardian = models.ForeignKey(Guardian)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) # When was this relationship established?
```

In that case you have to be aware that since you declared an explicit intermediate model,
that this is the model to use when creating a relationship between a guardian and a child.

e.g.

```
ChildGuardianMembership.objects.create(child=child_inst, guardian=guardian_inst)
```

Adding extra fields on many2many relationships(as above) is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling I was missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Relations are already bidirectional unless this is explicitly disabled.